# VueJS: Need to clear browser cache before reloading page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser-cache

In my **VueJS** component, I'm getting `div` data from:

```
this.$refs.mydiv.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Then I'm using it to compute and set other `div`s height.

But each time I reload my page, I need to clear browser cache otherwise the `div`s height are messed up.

How can I fix it ?

This is what I'm expecting to get:
[image]

And this is what I get after reloading if I don't clear browser cache:
[image]

Below is the **VueJS** component I'm using with **Laravel** (not sure if it's possible to adapt it to Stackoverflow snippet).

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div
      class="col- tree"
      ref="perbase"
    >
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a ref="per1">Grand parent</a>
          <ul ref="per2">
            <li>
              <a>parent 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>parent 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>parent 3</a>
              <ul ref="per3">
                <li>
                  <a>child 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a>child 2</a>
                  <ul ref="per4">
                    <li>
                      <a>grand child</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a>grand grand child</a>
                          <ul ref="per5">
                            <li>
                              <a>grand grand grand child</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div
      class="periods col-"
      ref="periods"
    >
      <div
        class="period p1"
        v-bind:style="{ height: p1height + 'px' }"
      >1</div>
      <div
        class="period p2"
        v-bind:style="{ height: p2height + 'px' }"
      >2</div>
      <div
        class="period p3"
        v-bind:style="{ height: p3height + 'px' }"
      >3</div>
      <div
        class="period p4"
        v-bind:style="{ height: p4height + 'px' }"
      >4</div>
      <div
        class="period p5"
        v-bind:style="{ height: p5height + 'px' }"
      >5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isMounted: false,
      base: '',
      botP1: '',
      botP2: '',
      botP3: '',
      botP4: '',
      botP5: '',
      p1height: '',
      p2height: '',
      p3height: '',
      p4height: '',
      p5height: ''
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.base = this.$refs.perbase.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    this.botP1 = this.$refs.per2.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    this.botP2 = this.$refs.per3.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    this.botP3 = this.$refs.per4.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    this.botP4 = this.$refs.per5.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    this.botP5 = this.$refs.perbase.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    this.p1height = this.botP1 - this.base - 10;
    this.p2height = this.botP2 - this.botP1;
    this.p3height = this.botP3 - this.botP2 - 10;
    this.p4height = this.botP4 - this.botP3;
    this.p5height = this.botP5 - this.botP4 + 20;
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
div.periods {
  width: 50px;
}

div.period {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.p1 {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
div.p2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
div.p3 {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
div.p4 {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
div.p5 {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

/*Now the CSS*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover + ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover + ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover + ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover + ul::before,
.tree li a:hover + ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I think we need way more context... Please provided a [mcve].

Comment: You can probably use CSS [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align your element heights

Comment: @Shadow I've just added the code I'm using.

Comment: @Phil Not sure how flexbox would help to fix this issue.

Comment: @Vignesh How to return a parameter from previous page ?

Comment: ok was wrong and i'll take back my comment